# Does RabbitMQ support hash partition like Kafka?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ with multiple consumers subscribed on a single queue. And I want the messages with same hash key can be consumed by the same consumer for each time. I know the default behavior for RabbitMQ is loop through all consumers and dispatch the message 1 by 1.

Does it have the same ability like Kafka partition?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding

Answer (score 4):

Well not exactly but a very close one .

You need to use RabbitMQ Consistent Hash Exchange Type which is available by adding the [rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/master/deps/rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange). It adds a consistent-hash exchange type to RabbitMQ. This exchange type uses consistent hashing  to distribute messages between the bound queues. It is recommended to get a basic understanding of the concept before evaluating this plugin and its alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

[Rebalancer](https://dradoaica.blogspot.com/2020/05/rebalancer.html) (forked from Jack Vanlightly and improved)

Create Kafka style consumer groups in other technologies. Rebalancer was born of the need for consumer groups with RabbitMQ. But Rebalancer is completely technology agnostic and will balance activity over any group of resources across a group of participating nodes.
Use cases
Create Kafka-like "consumer groups" with messaging technologies like RabbitMQ, SQS, etc.
Consume a group of resources such as file shares, FTPs, S3 buckets between the instances of a scaled out application.
Single Active-Consumer / Active-Backup
Create an application cluster that consumes a single resource in a highly available manner. The cluster leader (Coordinator) consumes the single resource and the slaves (Followers) remain idle in backup in case the leader dies.